# Contextmenu not showing up in ListActivity

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, listactivity

I'm using practically the same code in a different ListActivity, and it's working, but in this one it doesn't work.

This is the code for the context menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


    menu.setHeaderTitle("Anything");
    menu.add(0, ContextMenu.NONE, 0, "Unsubscribe");
}
```

And this is the entire ListActivity:

public class UnwatchedEpisodesActivity extends ListActivity{

```
private ArrayList<Episode> episodeList = new ArrayList<Episode>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    displayEpisodes();

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


    menu.setHeaderTitle("Anything");
    menu.add(0, ContextMenu.NONE, 0, "Unsubscribe");
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? When i long press an item, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In on **onCreate()** add this call:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything..

Comment: Nevermind, that did it. But I had to put it inside `displayEpisodes()` since this class is a tab inside a tabhost.